# Objective-C initializing an NSArray vs NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray, nsarray

Why does this work:

```
self.array = newArray;
```

But this doesn't:

```
[[self mutableArray] addObject:object];
```

Meaning, why do I need to init the `NSMutableArray` for it to work when I don't have to init the `NSArray`?

EDIT: Hops this is clearer guys.

Interface:

```
@interface Foo : UIViewController {

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *array;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *mutableArray;

@end
```

Implementation:

```
@implementation Foo

@synthesize array;
@synthesize mutableArray;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.array = [Class returningAnArray];
    [[self mutableArray] addObject:objectIHaveOmittedTheCode];
}

@end
```

Comment: The code you provided does not work by itself, and the question makes no sense, please clarify or this post will be closed.

Comment: There's not enough information there to make a determination about either case. How is `newArray` created? What is `self`, and does it have a `mutableArray` method? If so, what does it return? If it's a property, has it been initialized? Finally, what are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: I see your edit but the implementation doesn't match the interface. Please edit again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
self.array = newArray;
```

In this line, you are assigning already created object to `self.array`. So, you've no need to create it.

```
[[self mutableArray] addObject:object];
```

But in this line you are trying to add an object to a array which is not created actually. If you don't create the array, it will be `nil`, and sending message to nil won't take any effect.

Answer (score 2):

In Objective-C [NSArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) objects are immutable.

```
self.array = newArray;
```

This line is a property assignment. The `self.array` property returns a reference pointing to a location in memory that contains an [NSArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) object. By assigning the property to different objects you're not really modifying the object themselves.

If you wish to modify an existing [NSArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) object, you'll have to create a [NSMutableArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html) object containing the same elements:

```
NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:self.array];
[mutableArray addObject:object];
```

Note that [NSMutableArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html) inherits from [NSArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html), so you can safely assign the object referenced by `mutableArray` to any variable of type [NSArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html).

Comment: Just to be clear, it's actually an assignment to a property. There may or may not be a variable named `array` in self.

Answer (score 2):

`[Class returningArray]` did the allocation for you. Every object needs to be allocated (and should be initialized) before it can used. The solution is.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.array = [Class returningAnArray];
    self.mutableArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    //Now you can use mutable array
    [[self mutableArray] addObject:objectIHaveOmittedTheCode];
}
```

Now you have created your array and your mutable array with out explicitly calling alloc on either because those classes have done it for you.